# Override default Powershell handler for CTRL+L

Tags: powershell, overriding, handler

I was trying to override the default handler for a particular command in *PowerShell*, in my case I want to change the behavior I have when pressing **CTRL**+**L**. 
This is how my `Microsoft.Powershell_profile.ps1` file looks like right now:

```
function vim($File) {
    $File = $File.Replace('\', '/')
    bash -c "vim $File"
}
```

I have specified a function that executes `bash -c vim` every time I try to invoke `vim` on PowerShell. 
Is there a similar way to do that with **CTRL**+**L** using the configuration file for PS?

Comment: I'm assuming you're on Windows PowerShell v5.1 since you didn't specify.  Look at `PSReadLine` config to change handling of key combos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with:

```
Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Chord Ctrl+l -Function <FunctionName>
```

Also, I had problems with the screen buffer size (it was too small), which caused me issues on clearing the screen correctly and prevented me from scrolling up on PowerShell. I just changed the  settings this way:

`Properties > Layout > Screen buffer size > Height > 9001`

Thanks to @TheIncorrigible1

Comment: You can modify the buffer by looking at the `$Host.UI.RawUI` object fyi